# making a python package behave as a native cli app

Tags: python, linux, command-line

I have a python package which I can use on the command line as

```
python -m pkgname [args]
```

I want to give it native-like behaviour (on linux)

```
pkgname [args]
```

how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo chmod a+x pkname.py
$ ln -s $(pwd)/pkgname.py /usr/bin/pkgname
```

this really has nothing to do with python (the first line makes it executable... the second line maps it to a place on your path

make sure the first line of pkname.py is

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Comment: how does this change if `pkgname` is a directory with `__init__.py`, `__main__.py` and other scripts.

Comment: it shouldnt at all ... I dont think

Comment: `#!/usr/bin/env python` is a better shebang if your python doesn't happen to be in /usr/bin/python (it could be in /usr/local/bin, it could be a virtualenv, etc...)

Answer (score 1):

Use a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)).

Maybe something like putting this in the first line of the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Also you'll have to make it executable with `chmod +x pkgname.py` and make it available to the path.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `shebang` line by adding `#!/usr/bin/python` at the leading of your pack file ! then make your pack executable by run `chmod +x pkgname.py` in your terminal !

also as an alternative answer you can use `alias` :

`alias pkgname="python -m pkgname"`

Comment: what if there is no such file as pkgname.py, just the pkgname directory?

Comment: did you mean that your file name is `pkgname` and not `pkgname.py` ?

Comment: there is a folder called `pkgname` which contains a `__main__.py` which does the cli parsing

Comment: The "acepted way to do this is to have a single short script that simply calls out to the main script - and that way you invoke a script, rather than a module.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a [setup.py script](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html) that will install the package. Once you've written setup.py you can install the package locally

```
python setup.py install
```

or build packages in a zillion ways (well, a few less than a zillion) that you copy to the machines you want. The current packaging craze is python + pip + wheels, so

```
python setup.py bdist_wheel
```

Creates a file whose name encodes several details, look in dist/*.whl to find out what it is. Then on the target machine

```
pip intall path/to/the/crazily-named.whl
```