# Converting a python package to a 'native' CLI program

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, command-line-interface, jupyter

There are several questions/answers here on Stackoverflow (such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895515/making-a-python-package-behave-as-a-native-cli-app)) regarding this topic; however, they all seem to suggest just making the file executable and adding a shebang at the top of the file. I was wondering how something like `jupyter` (`notebook`, `lab`, etc) are able to do this without seemingly requiring users to explicitly make the file executable or add it to their path. Is there an easier way?

The `jupyter notebook` `setup.py` file can be found [here](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/blob/master/setup.py) for reference - nothing immediately jumps out at me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you're asking, this can be handled in the `setup.py` as you say.

```py
setup(
    name='example',
    ...
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'Foo = program.run:main',
        ]
    },
    ...
)
```

Here, I'm assuming you have a function `program.run()` which will parse any arguments provided through the terminal (using `sys.argv`, `argparse`, `click`, etc). You'd therefore run the program using: `Foo -args`. You can add as many entry points as you like.